# Using If Statement with 2D Array

Tags: android, android-intent, if-statement, expandablelistview

I am working with `ExpandableListView` right now. I need help how to use if-statement, if the condition is in 2D array. I already wrote this code, but when I tap on **every** child, it always goes to **Games** activity. What I want is when every child is tapped, new activity (depends on what child) will be opened.

I'm new in OOP. So maybe you can help me. Thanks!

```
listView.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
        if ( CHILDREN[0][0] == "Management") {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Information.this, Games.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        else if ( CHILDREN[0][1] == "Accountant") {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Information.this, Test.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        else if ( CHILDREN[0][2] == "Economy") {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Information.this, Chat.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        else {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Information.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

If it helps -- This is the string array declaration:

```
     private String[][] CHILDREN = { 
        { "Management", "Accountant", "Economy" },
        { "IAB", "Communication" , "Hospitality" },
        { "English", "Theology", "BK", "Elementary" },
        { "Machine", "Electrical", "Industrial" },
        { "Law" },
        { "Doctor" },
        { "Psychology" },
        { "Biology" },
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should build your if statement with ref to `childPosition`
like this

```
String selString = CHILDREN[groupPosition][childPosition];//parent.getItemAtPosition(childPosition).toString();
```

then

```
 if ( selString.equals("Management"))
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Information.this, Games.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
```

and so on...

Comment: I try this, but it ended up with every child goes to **else** condition (goes to MainActivity.class). I add my string array declaration if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try `CHILDREN[0][0].equals("Management"))` instead of `CHILDREN[0][0] == "Management"`

Comment: The output is still the same. When I tap on every child, it always goes to Games activity.

Answer (score 0):

```
listView.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {
@Override
public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
    if ( CHILDREN[groupPosition][childPosition] == "Management") {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Information.this, Games.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    else if ( CHILDREN[groupPosition][childPosition] == "Accountant") {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Information.this, Test.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    else if ( CHILDREN[groupPosition][childPosition] == "Economy") {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Information.this, Chat.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    else {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Information.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    return true;
}
});
```

Try this (hope, final code :) )

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you meant. What I want to do is when child list is tapped, it will go to new activity and every child must set to different new activity.

Comment: Your if statement is wrong. Try to use second listener - it checks what child is clicked and runs proper code

Comment: Almost like CRUSADER's answer, and this works well too. Thank you! :D